# Change color of rows depending on user input in a QTableView

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtableview

I'll start by explaining my goal. An e-commerce order containing several products are loaded into a qtableview. The user of the program will scan the ean codes of the products and if the ean code exist in the qtableview, the row should change colour to green or yellow. If the quantity of one product is greater than 1, the colour should turn yellow untill the quantity of scanned products equal the quantity in the order,

The overall goal is to make a quick and easy way to make sure correct products are placed in the correct order.

I have found a lot of answers of how to change colours of row permanently, but not how to change colours based on user input and changing values in the model.

Example of what i want to achieve.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are the following alternatives:

- `QIdentityProxyModel`: You must overwrite the data method and you calculate the color using the values, and if the color is different from the preset, set the background color to the original model.

  ```
  import sys
  import random
  from functools import partial
  from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


  def calculate_color(model, row):
      max_value = int(model.index(row, 2).data())
      current_value = int(model.index(row, 3).data())
      if current_value == 0:
          return QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.white)
      elif max_value == current_value:
          return QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.green)
      else:
          return QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.yellow)


  class IdentityProxyModel(QtCore.QIdentityProxyModel):
      def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
          if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole and index.column() in (2, 3):
              sm = self.sourceModel()
              row = index.row()
              color = calculate_color(sm, row)
              if color is not None and color != index.data(QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole):
                  for i in range(sm.columnCount()):
                      sm.setData(sm.index(row, i), color, QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole)
          return super(IdentityProxyModel, self).data(index, role)


  class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
      def __init__(self, parent=None):
          super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

          self.tableView = QtWidgets.QTableView()
          self.setCentralWidget(self.tableView)

          self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
          self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Prod Name", "EAN","Quanyity", "Counted"])

          proxy = IdentityProxyModel(self)
          proxy.setSourceModel(self.model)
          self.tableView.setModel(proxy)

          data = [["Prod1", "123456", 0, 0],
                  ["Prod2", "234567", 0, 0],
                  ["Prod3", "345678", 0, 0]]

          for r, rowData in enumerate(data):
              for c, d in enumerate(rowData):
                  it = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(d))
                  self.model.setItem(r, c, it)

          # launch test
          for i in range(self.model.rowCount()):
              self.reset(i)

      def reset(self, row):
          max_value = random.randint(1, 10)
          self.model.item(row, 2).setText(str(max_value))
          self.model.item(row, 3).setText("0")
          QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1000, partial(self.start_test, row))

      def start_test(self, row):
          max_value = int(self.model.item(row, 2).text())
          time_line = QtCore.QTimeLine(1000*max_value, self)
          time_line.setFrameRange(0, max_value)
          time_line.frameChanged.connect(partial(self.update_value, row))
          # reset after 3 seconds of completion
          time_line.finished.connect(lambda r=row: QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(3000, partial(self.reset, r)))
          time_line.start()

      def update_value(self, r, i):
          model = self.tableView.model()
          ix = model.index(r, 3)
          model.setData(ix, str(i))


  if __name__ == '__main__':
      app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
      w = MainWindow()
      w.resize(640, 480)
      w.show()
      sys.exit(app.exec_())
  ```
- Delegate: You must overwrite the paint method as it is called when there is a change in the model and calculate the color using the values, and if the color is different from the preset, set the background color to the original model.

  ```
  import sys
  import random
  from functools import partial
  from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


  def calculate_color(model, row):
      max_value = int(model.index(row, 2).data())
      current_value = int(model.index(row, 3).data())
      if current_value == 0:
          return QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.white)
      elif max_value == current_value:
          return QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.green)
      else:
          return QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.yellow)


  class ColorDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
      def paint(self, painter, option, index):
          if index.column() in (2, 3):
              model = index.model()
              r = index.row()
              color = calculate_color(model, r)
              if color != index.data(QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole):
                  for i in range(model.columnCount()):
                      model.setData(model.index(r, i), color, QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole)
          super(ColorDelegate, self).paint(painter, option, index)


  class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
      def __init__(self, parent=None):
          super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

          self.tableView = QtWidgets.QTableView()
          self.setCentralWidget(self.tableView)

          self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
          self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Prod Name", "EAN","Quanyity", "Counted"])

          self.tableView.setModel(self.model)
          self.tableView.setItemDelegate(ColorDelegate(self))

          data = [["Prod1", "123456", 0, 0],
                  ["Prod2", "234567", 0, 0],
                  ["Prod3", "345678", 0, 0]]

          for r, rowData in enumerate(data):
              for c, d in enumerate(rowData):
                  it = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(d))
                  self.model.setItem(r, c, it)

          # launch test
          for i in range(self.model.rowCount()):
              self.reset(i)

      def reset(self, row):
          max_value = random.randint(1, 10)
          self.model.item(row, 2).setText(str(max_value))
          self.model.item(row, 3).setText("0")
          QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1000, partial(self.start_test, row))

      def start_test(self, row):
          max_value = int(self.model.item(row, 2).text())
          time_line = QtCore.QTimeLine(1000*max_value, self)
          time_line.setFrameRange(0, max_value)
          time_line.frameChanged.connect(partial(self.update_value, row))
          # reset after 3 seconds of completion
          time_line.finished.connect(lambda r=row: QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(3000, partial(self.reset, r)))
          time_line.start()

      def update_value(self, r, i):
          model = self.tableView.model()
          ix = model.index(r, 3)
          model.setData(ix, str(i))


  if __name__ == '__main__':
      app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
      w = MainWindow()
      w.resize(640, 480)
      w.show()
      sys.exit(app.exec_())
  ```